# How is this working? Do closures run implicit loops?

Tags: swift, closures

Trying to learn my way through Swift after doing some other languages. I'm following a course with some training challenges and such. At some point there's a challenge which solution is sort of this:

```
for offset in offsets {
    if let matchIndex = expenses.items.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == expenses.businessItems[offset].id}){
            expenses.items.remove(at: matchIndex)
    }
}
```

The thing I cannot get my head around is. What does `$0.id` mean? How does it get a different value each time and thus is compared with `expenses.businessItems[offset].id` in order for `==` to work?

Is the closure some sort of implicit for loop iterating over `expenses.items`? Why?

Comment: Not the closure itself but `firstIndex(where:)` loops through the array until it finds an object that matches the condition in the closure, if any.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson how do you know firstIndex(where:) does the loop? if I may ask

Comment: By reading the documentation and articles and by using it myself in my code.

Comment: Because by basic algorithm logic, and its name being `firstIndex(where:)`, we can strongly assume it iterates the object ("array"), and stop when finding the correct condition and returning the index if found any... Then, we can check it also by debugging, or checking the doc.

Comment: Regarding the `$0.id`, it's the Shorthand argument name (see https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102). It's means here: the `currentExpenseofTheiteration`, then check its `id` property to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expenses.items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == expenses.businessItems[offset].id })
```

Is shorthand for this version which uses an explicit argument name

```
expenses.items.firstIndex(where: { expense in
  expense.id == expenses.businessItems[offset].id
})
```

which is a closure (AKA an anonymous function, or a block). To make it really clear, that's shorthand for

```
func expenseMatchesCurrentBusinessItem(_ expense: Expense) -> Bool {
   return expense.id == expenses.businessItems[offset].id
}

expenses.items.firstIndex(where: expenseMatchesCurrentBusinessItem)
```

Basically, it's a boolean function for checking if a given expense matches the one specified by the offset into the `businessItems` array. `firstIndex(where:)` accepts this function as its parameter and internally loops through its array calling that function with each element. If the provided function returns true, `firstIndex(where:)` returns the index for that element. Note that locally declared functions and closures have access to the variables declared in the same scope, which is how the function can access `expenses` and `offset`.

Once you get used to functional programming, that full example looks *way* too verbose. In general `expenseMatchesCurrentBusinessItem` is just "the function that tests if this is the thing we want" and its parameter `expense` is just "the thing in the array" so rather than name either of them, we use the unnamed anonymous closure syntax and the automatic argument name `$0`

Comment: This answer is good, but considering OP specifically mentioned not understanding what `$0.id`, and is trying to understand Swift (ie. is new to Swift), I think a good improvement would be to add a short explanation `$0` is just a specific example of referring to unnamed closure parameters by position, specifically the 1st parameter, and that `$1` would refer to the second parameter, if it has one, etc…  An analogy with positional parameters in shell scripting might be helpful for those who have that knowledge.  Such things aren’t necessarily obvious to those new to the language.

Comment: "How does it get a different value each time" made me think that they had a bigger misunderstanding in their head. But I think your comment covers the parameter names pretty well :)